# Getting Dataflowrunner with --experiments=upload_graph to work

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline that produces a dataflow graph (serialized JSON representation) that exceeds the allowable limit for the API, and thus cannot be launched via the dataflow runner for apache beam as one would normally do. And running dataflow runner with the instructed parameter `--experiments=upload_graph` does not work and fails saying there are no steps specified .

When getting notified about this size problem via an error, the following information is provided:

```
the size of the serialized JSON representation of the pipeline exceeds the allowable limit for the API. 

Use experiment 'upload_graph' (--experiments=upload_graph)
to direct the runner to upload the JSON to your 
GCS staging bucket instead of embedding in the API request.
```

Now using this parameter, does indeed result in dataflow runner uploading an additional `dataflow_graph.pb` file to the staging location beside the usual pipeline.pb file. Which I verified actually exists in gcp storage.

However the job in gcp dataflow then immediately fails after start with the following error:

```
Runnable workflow has no steps specified.
```

I've tried this flag with various pipelines, even apache beam example pipelines and see the same behaviour.

This can be reproduced by using word count example:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
      -DarchetypeVersion=2.11.0 \
      -DgroupId=org.example \
      -DartifactId=word-count-beam \
      -Dversion="0.1" \
      -Dpackage=org.apache.beam.examples \
      -DinteractiveMode=false
```

```
cd word-count-beam/
```

Running it without the `experiments=upload_graph` parameter works: 
(make sure to specify your project, and buckets if you want to run this)

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
     -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner --project=<your-gcp-project> \
                  --gcpTempLocation=gs://<your-gcs-bucket>/tmp \
                  --inputFile=gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/* --output=gs://<your-gcs-bucket>/counts" \
     -Pdataflow-runner
```

Running it with the `experiments=upload_graph` results in pipe failing with message `workflow has no steps specified`

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
     -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner --project=<your-gcp-project> \
                  --gcpTempLocation=gs://<your-gcs-bucket>/tmp \
                  --experiments=upload_graph \
                  --inputFile=gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/* --output=gs://<your-gcs-bucket>/counts" \
     -Pdataflow-runner
```

Now I would expect that dataflow runner would direct gcp dataflow to read the steps from the bucket specified as seen in the source code:

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowRunner.java#L881

However this seems not to be the case. Has anyone gotten this to work, or has found some documentation regarding this feature that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Unfortunately this experimental flag `--experiments=upload_graph` is not yet supported on the Dataflow yet. Reference [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6049)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The experiment has since been reverted and the messaging will be corrected in Beam 2.13.0

Revert [PR](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/8122)

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue and the solution was quite silly.  I had quite a complex dataflow streaming job developed and it was working fine and the next day stopped working with error "Runnable workflow has no steps specified.". In my case, someone specified `pipeline().run().waitUntilFinish()` twice after creating options and due to that, I was getting this error. Removing the duplicate pipeline run resolved the issue. I still think there should be some useful error trace by beam/dataflowrunner in this scenario.